# Identify who is using a certificate via weblogic

Tags: java, certificate, weblogic

Is there a way to identify which application is using a particular certificate? Especially one issued by GTE CyberTrust. 
We have different certs used by our application in making outgoing connection to other applications. I was wondering if this can be displayed in Weblogic Server Admin Console? If not can they be displayed via other methods?

Answer (score 1):

I think what makes this tricky is there are many ways to "use" a certificate.

To start with a certificate can be stored in an individual keystore, or inside jre/lib/security/cacerts, on weblogic admin console configuration, or passed using java system property -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore. It can be used by classes such as SSLSocket, or any arbitrary library that uses this class, or configured via Spring xml.

Typically an application would "use" a certificate if it made a HTTPS connection into a domain with matching CN. I would begin by searching the source code for this (eg: search for SSLSocket / HTTPS / the CN name)

Comment: Thanks gerry, i'll try looking for this.

Comment: Another option (although not via the console) is to look in the DefaultAuditRecorder.log file on your managed server. This file should contain login/cert information and can probably give you the info you're looking for.